# Return a new object whose properties are those in the given object and whose keys are present in the given array.

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

:) I need to return a new object whose properties are those in the given object and whose keys are present in the given array.

code attempt:

```
var arr = ['a', 'c', 'e'];
var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
};

function select(arr, obj) {
 var result = {};
 var array = [];
 for (var key in obj){
   array.push(key);
 }
var num = arr.length + obj.length; 
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
     for(var j = 0; j < num; j++) {
       if (arr[i] === array[j]) {

       result.array[i] = obj.arr[i];
     }
     }
    }
    return result;
}
```

(incorrect) result:

```
{}
```

desired result:

```
// --> { a: 1, c: 3 }
```

Any advice? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Longer, but more readable version:

```js
var arr = ['a', 'c', 'e'],
    obj = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},
    hash = {};
    
arr.forEach(function(v){     //iterate over each element from arr
  Object.keys(obj).some(function(c){  //check if any key from obj is equal to iterated element from arr
    if (v == c) {
      hash[v] = obj[c]; //if it is equal, make a new key inside hash obj and assign it's value from obj to it
    }
  });
});

console.log(hash);
```

Short version:

```js
var arr = ['a', 'c', 'e'],
    obj = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},
    hash = {};
    
arr.forEach(v => Object.keys(obj).some(c => v == c ? hash[v] = obj[c] : null));

console.log(hash);
```

Comment: you need two iteration of of array, whereas one is sufficient. the big o goes from O(n) (single loop) to O(n²) (nested loops).

Comment: @NinaScholz You mean it's wrong? Can you tell me more about it? And about two loops, you also have two loops (forEach, for in). You have intrigued me.

Comment: if have used the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) which is different from the [`for ... in` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). it uses a single loop for the array of the wanted properties, with a check if the properties exists in the source object.

Comment: @NinaScholz Oh my... I wasn't aware of it. Thank you Nina!

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate the given keys, test if it is a key in the object and assign the value to the same key in the result object.

```js
function select(arr, obj) {
    var result = {};
    arr.forEach(function (k) {
        if (k in obj) {
            result[k] = obj[k];
        }
    });
    return result;
}

var arr = ['a', 'c', 'e'],
    obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };

console.log(select(arr, obj));
```

Comment: Ms. Scholz, Yes for me, it is helpful seeing different ways to solve these problems! I do appreciate you taking the time to answer my question. I checked @KindUser's response as the answer b/c s/he explained each step, which for me, as a new learner, is helpful. It's all a lot to take in and I'm trying to learn. I'm very grateful for your input! :) Thank you!